# Terraform: depends_on for module not working as expected in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am new to terraform. I was working with terraform v0.12 previously and since I wanted to bring in a dependency between modules, I started using terraform v0.13 recently. I am trying to create an IAM role and attach a few policies to the created role. But the issue arises in policy attachment to the role. Few policies are getting attached to the role but some policies throw an error saying no such role exists while the other policies are attached to the role properly. Is there anything wrong in my implementation?

module.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-1"
}

#Control Plane role and policies

module "ControlPlane_Role" {

  source = "../../templates/IAM/roles"
  role_name = var.EKS-master-role
}

module "ControlPlane_Policy1" {

  source = "../../templates/IAM/aws_policy"
  role_name = var.EKS-master-role
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  depends_on = [module.ControlPlane_Role.role_create]
}

module "ControlPlane_Policy2" {

  source = "../../templates/IAM/aws_policy"
  role_name = var.EKS-master-role
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
  depends_on = [module.ControlPlane_Role.role_create]
}
```

templates/IAM/roles/role.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_create" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.trusted_entity.json
  name               = var.role_name
}
```

aws_policy.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_policy" {
  role       = var.role_name
  policy_arn = var.policy_arn
}
```

I'll be passing the variable files separately and there are no issues with that.

Error:

```
Error: Error attaching policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy to IAM Role EKS-master: NoSuchEntity: The role with name EKS-master cannot be found.

Error attaching policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy to IAM Role EKS-master: NoSuchEntity: The role with name EKS-master cannot be found.
```

If I re-run the command terraform apply again on the same resources without any change, the policies are getting attached.

Comment: The fact that re-running Terraform made this succeed makes me suspect that this is an example of an unfortunately-typical AWS IAM behavior whereby changes can take several minutes to propagate across all AWS services in all regions. The IAM API provides no way to confirm that a change has fully propagated, so unfortunately sometimes Terraform moves too fast tries to make use of a policy that it has successfully created before the creation has propagated to, in this case, EKS. Because this is a limitation of the underlying API, there unfortunately aren't any great workarounds.

Comment: Yes @MartinAtkins, I agree with your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `depends_on` except for some exceptional cases. From the `templates/IAM/roles`, define an output that is the name of the role and in the other modules pass this output (`role_name = module.ControlPlane_Role.output_role_name`). With this setup, the dependency graph is clear (create the role, create the things that depend on the role) instead of having to manually define dependencies with `depends_on`.